# IBM Watson Assistant: Chat Bot Entity Distinction

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have two entities called **@amount** and **@type** . **@type** has values like ***"A1BM"***, ***"C3MH"*** and **@amount** has values such as ***"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"*** . Whenever the user enters **"A1BM 10"**, I want the bot to recognize that **"10"** not as an **@amount** but rather as the size of the **@type**.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

[You can use patterns (regular expressions) to define entities](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-entities), e.g., for the format of **@amount**. Watson Assistant also has system entities that can be enabled, e.g., [@sys-number](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/system-entities.html#sys-number) for detecting different forms and written formats of numbers. Moreover, when checking for matches you can also access the entire input string, locations of detected objects (intents, entities, ...) and the confidence of a detection.

You did not share details about how the responses will be entered. Your best bet seems to me to add a pattern for @type, use a number pattern or @sys-number for @amount and compare the location and relative neighborhood of entered values to detect that "10" is meant as size and not as amount.

There are some examples in the documentation.